# Is this sql where statement correct?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, datetime, select, where-clause

I have 10 rows for today's date but my select statement based on date dosen't seem to work....

```
SELECT Id,WirelessId,RegNo,DriverName1,MobileNo1,DriverName2,MobileNo1 from
 DailySchedule where IsDeleted=0 and CreatedDate='2010-05-28'
```

Any suggestion...

Comment: First of: what does "not work" mean? Do you get no results? Chances are your `CreatedDate` has a time component. In that case you only query for those rows that happen exactly at midnight.

Comment: What type is the column CreatedDate?

Comment: @spender and @joachim its a Datetime field..

Comment: check the posted answer will work for you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only if the dates assigned to them are midnight today. It might be better to do:

```
CreatedDate BETWEEN '2010-05-28 00:00' AND '2010-05-29 00:00'
```

Comment: A safer format is to have a 'T' between the date and time, instead of a space character. (Safer in terms of SQL server always gets the conversion right, no matter what locale/datetime settings are applied, and where)

Comment: You will miss enty entries in the last minute, take a look at http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-does-between-work-with-dates-in-sql-

Comment: That is not fixed either since now you will get the entries at exactly midnight. A better way would be and CreatedDate >='20100528'
and CreatedDate < '20100529'  also your dateformat is not safe, use ISO (YYYYMMDD) formats

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the entries for May 28th I would do

```
and CreatedDate >='20100528'
and CreatedDate < '20100529'
```

Notice the safe ISO format (YYYYMMDD)  no dashes

Also take a look at [How Does Between Work With Dates In SQL Server?](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-does-between-work-with-dates-in-sql-) to see why between can not give you all the results you want

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that CreatedDate is a datetime or a date, I don't see what's wrong with the syntax of the where clause. Maybe the IsDeleted field for those columns is actually NULL? (Or non-zero, at any rate.)

Edit: what Dave says, or DATE(CreatedDate) = '2010-05-28'

Answer (score 0):

I'd check to see the type of the CreatedDate column and make sure that the string you're passing is being converted to a date properly.

When you say you 'have' 10 rows, is that confirmed visually or with a query executed in a console?

Comment: query executed in a consule without where clause

Answer (score 0):

Not enough info to go on but I suspect that your dates have a time component and so don't match the string exactly.

Try using:

```
datediff(day, CreatedDate, '28-may-2010')) = 0
```

Comment: That is non SARGable, the optimizer needs to do a scan

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id,WirelessId,RegNo,DriverName1,MobileNo1,DriverName2,MobileNo1 from
 DailySchedule where IsDeleted=0 and date_format(CreatedDate, "%Y-%m-%d")='2010-05-28'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work too

```
select Id, 
  WirelessId,
  RegNo,
  DriverName1,
  MobileNo1,
  DriverName2,
  MobileNo1 
from DailySchedule 
where IsDeleted=0 
  and CONVERT(varchar,CreatedDate,101) ='05/28/2010'
```